# Having trouble with this code to replace bad words with random symbols

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and am trying to make a program that will ask for user text input and replace any bad words with a set of random symbols from a tuple of defined character symbols which matches the length of the bad word that the user inputted.
I keep getting this error and I don't know why:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "replace_bad_words.py", line
> 30, in 
> rchars = sample(chars, y)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/random.py", line 315, in sample
> raise ValueError("Sample larger than population") ValueError: Sample larger than population

New here and hoping for some feedback from this great community. Any suggestions for other communities to help debug python newbs would also be appreciated. And of course any tips for better, more efficient code to do what I am trying to do, or better coding style would also be great. Thanks.

```
from random import sample

# Make the bad word lists
bwlist = ['badword1', 'badword2', 'badword3', 'badword4', 'badword5', 'badword6', 'badword7', 'badword8']
bw2 = [wd + ',' for wd in bwlist]
bw3 = [wd + '.' for wd in bwlist]
bw4 = [wd + '!' for wd in bwlist]
bw5 = [wd + '?' for wd in bwlist]

chars = ('@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '!')

# Ask for some text input
aa = input('Write some words about yourself: ')

# Convert the user's text into a list of words
# Create a copy of the list
bb = aa.split()
cc = bb.copy()

# Create an empty string for joining random characters to replace the bad words
nsp = ''

# Loop through the list of words and store the index and length of the bad word
for i in bb :
    if i in bwlist :
        x = bb.index(i)
        y = len(i)

# Produce a list of random characters matching length of the bad word
        rchars = sample(chars, y)

# Replace the bad word with a string of random characters in the copy of the list
        cc[x] = nsp.join(rchars)

# Same as above, but removes punctuation from bad words
    elif i in bw2 or i in bw3 or i in bw4 or i in bw5 :
        x = bb.index(i)
        y = len(i) - 1
        rchars = sample(chars, y)
        cc[x] = nsp.join(rchars)

# Convert the list of user text back to a string with bad words replaced and print
sp = ' '
edited_user_inp = sp.join(cc)
print(edited_user_inp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `random.sample` here.  `sample(chars, y)` takes `y` distinct elements from `chars` shuffles them and returns the resulting list.  So if `y > len(chars)`, which is the case here, the function will raise a `ValueError`.
However if you make sure in your code that the length of any "bad word" is less or equal to the length of `chars`, this will work.  For example, I changed your definition of `chars` with this one:

```py
chars = ('@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '!')
```

this test gave:

```
Write some words about yourself: hello badword1 this is badword2.
hello %@$#@&$& this is %$$%!!@&
```

Another function of the `random` package that seems more suited to your need is `choices` that can randomly choose `k` items from a population and return the resulting list.  For example:

```py
>>> random.choices(('@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '!'), k=10)
['$', '&', '!', '&', '&', '&', '&', '!', '&', '!']
```

You see here that the same item may appear in the resulting list.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was some simple thing like that but I couldn't figure it out. You made my day. :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit off topic but I would suggest that you use set() instead of list since on large lists the lookup will be really slow.  Also you do not need separate lists for bad words with punctuation, just strip the punctuation before checking for bad word.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it. With the strip method?

Comment: I guess what I am going for, though, is to print out as close to exactly what the user typed in, but replacing the bad words with symbols. So if I did strip the punctuation, I wonder how I could put it back before printing?

Comment: > With the strip method?
Yeah .strip() will do the job.



Well, then keep the original word with punctuation, count the number of punctuation symbols before and after the word, then strip punctuation. If it is a bad word replace all symbols except the punctuation (easy since we have their counts before and after) with the required replacement symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Use [random.choices()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) instead of [random.sample()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) for generating your badword replacements. That's the cause of the error message you are seeing.

The error message states that 'Sample larger than population'. This error occurs when you call `sample(chars, y)` and `y > len(chars)`. `sample()` chooses randomly from the chars without replacement, which means the length of the replacement can be at most `len(chars)` long. `choices()` instead picks with replacement, meaning you can get arbitarily long replacements.

```
    from random import choices
    rchars = choices(chars, k=y)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for!